# How to create Enum class's object in JNI

Tags: enums, java-native-interface, native

please guide if any body knows how to create a Enum class's object in JNI

Thnx

Comment: Please clarify. The class is loaded, not created, and it is accessed from JNI via `FindClass(). But is that what you were asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to see a [blog article](http://mike-java.blogspot.com/2008/05/java-enum-in-java-native-interface-jni.html) on this topic. Is this what you were looking for?